# Treat similar elements as separate objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of similar objects that I want to find some CSS properties for. I don't have access to any classes or ids, as the user can customize these.

```
$("div").each(function() {
    $(this).width("foo");
});
```

Then I want to treat each element as a separate object and do things like find the div with the smallest width, then change the background color of that div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the smallest div, you can sort the divs and take the first one

```js
function ascending(a, b) {
    return $(a).width() - $(b).width();
}

var sorted = $('div').sort(ascending);
$(sorted[0]).css('border', '5px solid red');
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqPM7/)

*Update:*

Look at [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), the important part is how the compare function (e.g., ascending) is defined. It returns

- `< 0`, when a is less than b
- `0`, when a is equal to b
- `> 0`, when a is greater than b

As an alternative, you can just loop through the divs and compare the element's width

```js
var x = $('div')[0];
$('div').each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(this).width() < $(x).width())
        x = el;
});

$(x).css('border', '5px solid red');
```

This way you can compare with `<` or `>` or any other way you like. As a side effect, this version is more efficient than sorting the divs.

See updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqPM7/1/)

Comment: Awesome mate. How would I flip that to find the widest div? Change 0 to 1? Or change ascending to descending?

Comment: Got it working by changing 0 to 1. Thanks mate :)